# NSLayoutConstraint defined in code and bottom Layout Guide deprecated in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, nslayoutconstraint, safearealayoutguide

I have a viewController holding a constraint like this one:

```
self.subviewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.subviewConstraint,
                                                     attribute: .bottom,
                                                     relatedBy: .equal,
                                                     toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide,
                                                     attribute: .bottom,
                                                     multiplier: 1,
                                                     constant: 0)
```

and I'm being shown this warning:

> 'bottomLayoutGuide' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor instead of bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor

I'm only finding examples for setting anchors instead of `NSLayoutConstraint`s like this, and I don't fully understand this warning... "use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.**bottomAnchor** instead of bottomLayoutGuide.**topAnchor**"? How is that the bottom anchor of the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` matches the top anchor of the of the `bottomLayoutGuide`? Where could I find a good graphical explanation of this? 
How should I correctly rewrite my constraint to keep its current behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

**TopLayoutGuide** and **bottomLayoutGuide** are **deprecated** since **iOS 11**.

You could update your code with this, taking advantage of the new  **NSLayoutAnchor**:

```
self.subviewConstraint = self.subviewConstraint?.firstItem?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

or you can use the initializer of **NSLayoutConstraint** as in your question:

```
self.subviewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.subviewConstraint?.firstItem as Any,
                                                    attribute: .bottom,
                                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                                    toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                                                    attribute: .bottom,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: 0)
```

Note that I've changed your `self.subviewConstraint` parameter to `self.subviewConstraint.firstItem` instead, within the **NSLayoutConstraint** initialization method, because you were using the NSLayoutConstraint as the item.
I suppose this is some kind of typo you made.

Here you can find some good graphical explanation of the new **SafeArea** behaviour in **iOS 11** and above:
[iOS Safe Area - Medium.com](https://medium.com/rosberryapps/ios-safe-area-ca10e919526f)

Additionally, you said *"I'm only finding examples for setting anchors instead of NSLayoutConstraints"*, but I want to make it clear that the `constraint(equalTo:)` method of **NSLayoutAnchor** returns an **NSLayoutConstraint**. ([Apple NSLayoutAnchor documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor))